# Google OAuth 2 authorization - wrong confiemation link is generated

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-oauth

Trying to allow my application to read my gmail.

Created OAuth 2.0 client, set up redirect urls for it.

Started service and got prompt

```
Please visit this URL to authorize this application:
```

But this url has incorrect redirect_url param (it sets localhost:xxxxx where port is always a random number). This URL is not what I set up creating OAuth client (my redirect uris are on the same host as my application). So I can't authenticate my service to my gmail. Why?

Should the redirect uri return smth? I've read all the related questions, but can't find an answer.

Comment: Have you set the `redirect_uri` in your application? Does it match the one you set in the console? How are you setting it? Via downloaded Credentials file? Setting it directly with some method? What language are you using? Could you share a sample of the code you're using?

Comment: Yes, I have set redirect_uri in my application.
Yes, I added all possible variants with http/https, with and without /, with port and without.
I'm setting all redirect_uri during OAuth client creation.
I'm using Python.
I'll share some code a little later. 

The main question for me now is what should redirect_uri endpoint return?

Comment: Do you mean whether the response from the OAuth 2.0 server to the specified `redirect_uri` contains anything? That would be the [authorization code](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#handlingresponse).